# “The message exceeds the maximum supported size” while fetching attachment using outlook rest api

Tags: outlook-restapi

I am trying to fetch the attachment from Exchange Online using Outlook REST Mail API but it is giving 400 HTTP response -

```
Response Code: 400 Text:{"error":{"code":"ErrorMessageSizeExceeded","message":"The message exceeds the maximum supported size., The message exceeds the maximum supported size."}}
```

On Exchange Online I've configured the maximum email size as ~150 MiB. But with Outlook REST Mail API nor MS Graph API for mails I cannot fetch even 50 Mib messages with attachments.

My questions are:
1) What is the real limit for size in these APIs?
2) Is there any way to increase and/or avoid this limit?

Thank you.